# Captive Portal for Android Phone did not pop up

Tags: android, apache2, raspberry-pi3, dnsmasq, captiveportal

I used hostapd, dnsmasq and apache2 for implementing the wifi-hotspot with captive portal on my Raspberry Pi 3B+, before I implement this project, I have never get in touch with wifi networks. Hence I search a lot of post on how to implement one.

Below is the configuration I used:

/etc/apache/apache.conf:

```
# Apple
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CaptiveNetworkSupport(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192.168.0.200$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.0.200/index.html [L,R=302]

# Android
RedirectMatch 302 /generate_204 http://192.168.0.200/index.html

# All
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.0.200/index.html [L]

# 404 Redirect
ErrorDocument 404 http://192.168.0.200/index.html
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.0.201,192.168.0.210,255.255.255.0,24h
address=/#/192.168.0.200
```

I used Sony H4133, HUAWEI RNE-22, Redmi Note3, Samsung Galaxy S8+, Samsung Galaxy Tab S to test the portal. Only the Sony one work like a charm. Tab S can pop up a notification but when I click on it, it send me to google.com but not my portal. While others didn't even show the pop up.

I checked the access.log and find that the /generate_204 indeed 302 redirect to my page and return a 200 code. According to my research, any code return other than 204 should show up the pop up, but why it is not the case here?

access.log:

```
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:10 +0800] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 899 "-" "MQ 3.3.8/3.0 (Android 6.0.1) Xiaomi Redmi Note 3"
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:11 +0800] "GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 561 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 MIUI/V10.2.1.0.MHOMIXM)"
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:15 +0800] "POST /getconfig HTTP/1.1" 302 531 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 MIUI/V10.2.1.0.MHOMIXM)"
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:15 +0800] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 862 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 MIUI/V10.2.1.0.MHOMIXM)"
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:15 +0800] "POST /mistats/v2 HTTP/1.1" 302 531 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 MIUI/V10.2.1.0.MHOMIXM)"
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:15 +0800] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 862 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 MIUI/V10.2.1.0.MHOMIXM)"
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:20 +0800] "POST /mistats/v2 HTTP/1.1" 302 531 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 MIUI/V10.2.1.0.MHOMIXM)"
192.168.0.204 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:20:20 +0800] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 862 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 MIUI/V10.2.1.0.MHOMIXM)"



192.168.0.205 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:23:31 +0800] "GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 570 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; RNE-L22 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L22)"
192.168.0.205 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:23:31 +0800] "GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 560 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; RNE-L22 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L22)"
192.168.0.205 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:23:31 +0800] "GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 560 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; RNE-L22 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L22)"
192.168.0.205 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:23:44 +0800] "GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 570 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; RNE-L22 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L22)"
192.168.0.205 - - [04/Jan/2020:12:23:56 +0800] "GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 570 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; RNE-L22 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L22)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apache.conf` is your problem. Config Apache2 in another way.
Every operating system has its own different way of detecting Internet access.

The mechanism is this basically:

```
GET/POST http://x.com/bar.html
If bar.html == [expected content] > Open Internet
If bar.html != [expected content] > Captive Portal
If bar.html[status] != SUCCESS > No Network
```

Each device, also Android different manufactures, behaves differently. For example, look at this list:

```
xperia z5:
connectivitycheck.gstatic.com:80
clients3.google.com:80
---------------------
galaxy j3 2016:
172.217.21.14:80    connectivitycheck.android.com
---------------------
galaxy j7 2015:
172.16.98.10:80
connectivitycheck.gstatic.com:80
---------------------
galaxy note4:
nothing!
---------------------
ios 11:
captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html
---------------------
windows 10:
www.msftconnecttest.com
```

I suggest make another apache config file for each device/manufacture.

---

Create a directory for android in apache

```
cd /var/www/html/
sudo mkdir android
```

Create a simple index.html file that is going to appear on the splash page of the android device.

Create `android.conf`  in nano (or your favorite text editor) and copy the following code to create a "redirection rule" for Android devices.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/android.conf
```

Put these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Servername connectivitycheck.gstatic.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/android

    RedirectMatch 302 /generate_204 /index.html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/android_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/android_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Save file and exit.

Done. Follow the procedure for other devices. Also, check [this link](https://rootsh3ll.com/captive-portal-guide/) out to get more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detail explain, it did solve a lot for my confusion. I even implement the ios part with the help for your guide and tested successfully. However, the Samsung Tab S still act the same and I observe that it opens the chrome browser and navigate to google.com instead of opening a dedicated browser for the captive portal. Also, the Redmi and HuaWei device still have no pop up, I suspect that they are not using the standard captive portal checking site due to China internet control policies.

Comment: @AngusW My pleasure. Install a [packet monitoring package](https://linuxtechlab.com/install-wireshark-linux-centosubuntu/) and connect your phone to the raspberry pi, you'll find the request of devices. After that, add a new PHP config file to the new device. With Samsung devices, you can find the solution by this method but for the Chinese phone, it's a bit different.

Comment: Recently, I have configured a captive portal system on Raspberry pi with [the NoDosSplash](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88438/raspberry-pi-as-access-point-with-captive-portal/106018#106018). It's so great, however, I have the same problem with Chinese phone either. I asked about this problem in [this Github issue](https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash/issues/478), it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[Orlando Novas Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66146036/14386208), indeed setting dhcp range between 200.200.200.10/200.200.200.250 triggers captive portal and a pop-up saying sign in this wifi I'm using dnsmasq,

--dhcp-range=200.200.200.10,200.200.200.250,255.255.255.0,8h

And redirecting to apache server hosting the captive portal page --address=/#/200.200.200.1

Tested on:

•Samsung j7 pro 2019 Android 9 dhcp-9

•Samsung A70 2020 Android 11 dhcp-11

•Huawei p smart 2019 dhcp-10

•android 4.4 KitKat dhcp-5.5

Answer (score -1):

I tried several captive portals and none works for me with Samsung devices. I used 192.168.12.1 as the IP address.

In the end, after many tests, I found the solution: you can't use an IP address like 192.186.45.1 or the one I was using. So, I set the DNS server IP address to 200.200.200.1 and I set the DHCP server range to 200.200.200.10 - 200.200.200.250. After those changes, it worked for me on all the devices I tested, even on the Samsung Note 8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].